# How to use variables and functions declared in a header in C++

Tags: c++, header

First of all this might be messy, because I'm pretty new to programming in general.
Well I'm making a rpg game and I want all my weapons to be in a file called Weapons.cpp.
I made it so that I got all of my global variables such as "weaponDamage" and "weaponName" in a header file called common.h so that I can access and manipulate those variables from both my main and my .cpp file. But the problem is that it can't seem to find those variables and functions in my header.

Here's some code:

**common.h:**

```
#include <string>  
#ifndef COMMON_H_INCLUDED  
#define COMMON_H_INCLUDED  

//global variables  
extern int pureDamage = 0;  
extern int pureHealth = 0;  
extern int weaponDamage;  
extern int armorDefense;  
extern int totalDamage = pureDamage + weaponDamage;  
extern int totalHealth = pureHealth + armorDefense;  
extern int totalLuck;  
extern string starsign;  
extern string weaponName;  

//all weapons  

void weaponSwordIron();  
void weaponSwordGold();  
void weaponSwordSwordOfTheHeavens();  
void weaponBowSimple();  
void weaponBowLongBow();  
void weaponBowThunder();  
void weaponStaffStaffOfFlames();  
void weaponStaffStaffOfLightning();  
void weaponStaffStaffOfAssKicking();  

#endif // COMMON_H_INCLUDED
```

**Weapons.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>  
#include <common.h>  


using namespace std;

void weaponSwordIron()
{
    int weaponDamage = 5;
    string weaponName = "Iron Sword";
}
void weaponSwordGold()
{
    int weaponDamage = 8;
    string weaponName = "Gold Sword";
}
void weaponSwordSwordOfTheHeavens()
{
    int weaponDamage = 15;
    string weaponName = "Sword Of The Heavens";
}
void weaponBowSimple()
{
    int weaponDamage = 5;
    string weaponName = "Simple Bow";
}
void weaponBowLongBow()
{
    int weaponDamage = 8;
    string weaponName = "Long Bow";
}
void weaponBowThunder()
{
    int weaponDamage = 15;
    string weaponName = "Thunder Bow";
}
void weaponStaffStaffOfFlames()
{
    int weaponDamage = 5;
    string weaponName = "Staff Of Flames";
}
void weaponStaffStaffOfLightning()
{
    int weaponDamage = 8;
    string weaponName = "Staff Of Lightning";
}
void weaponStaffStaffOfAssKicking()
{
    int weaponDamage = 15;
    string weaponName = "Staff Of Ass Kicking";
}
```

and a little piece of my main, the function called `GiveWeapon()`:

```
void GiveWeapon()
{

    system("cls");
    if (starsign == "mage")
    {
        weaponSwordIron();
        cout << weaponDamage;
        cout << weaponName;
    }
    else if (starsign == "warrior")
    {
        weaponBowSimple();
    }
    else if (starsign == "archer")
    {
        weaponStaffStaffOfFlames();
    }
    else
    {
        ChooseStarsign();
    }
    AssignAttributes();
}
```

And yes I did remember to include common.h
Now the error my IDE `Code::Blocks` comes up with is : error: common.h: no such file or directory
I don't know why it comes up with that so please help.

Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the last thing you want to do as a new programmer is make an RPG. imo they need a much more robust design than other types of games, which starts with OOP.

Comment: you need to write `#include "common.h"`

Comment: Is the header in the same location as the cpp file?

Comment: Those tutors are getting imaginative

Comment: You should be avoiding global variables, I think.  Functions such as `void weaponSwordIron() {  
int weaponDamage = 5;  
string weaponName = "Iron Sword"; }` initialize two local variables which are destroyed when the function returns, rendering the initialization pointless.  The functions effectively do nothing.  If you dropped the types from the functions, you'd be modifying the global variables — which at least makes the functions useful (though I have reservations about the use of globals).

Comment: The `#include <string>` in 'common.h' should be inside the header guards (just after the `#define`).

Comment: No offence here, but you should start with some C++/OOD/OOP book/tutorial. Instead of functions, which does nothing, you should create interface class Weapon with `getName()` and `getDamage()` methods and subclass it for each weapon type. Also avoid writing `totalDamage = pureDamage + weaponDamage`, when `weaponDamage` value is unknown. C++ is not declarative language, you will end up with random value.

Comment: I think you should stop dead in your tracks and go back to basics, learning one step at a time.  I think you're jumping into projects that require more depth and complexity that what you've learned so far.  You're not even out of the console yet and trying to make an RPG?  Tsk tsk.  I recommend you read SAMS Teach Yourself C++ in [insert newest version here] from cover to cover while you're still learning syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Use `"common.h"` instead of `<common.h>`.
The angled ones are for library files.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: depending on the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `"common.h"` not `< common.h>`

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference for a standard conforming compiler.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It might.  The angle brackets means 'search in system defined locations only'; the quotes means 'search in perhaps some other places, then search in the system defined locations'.  Fortunately, the `-I` option counts as a system-defined location.

Comment: Angle brackets suppress warnings from header being included. Also, I can include local headers this way.

Answer (score 0):

weopens.cpp is mostly non-sense.

i tried compiling the following:

```
void a() {
 int b = 5; }

int main()
{
 a();
 return 0;
}
```

and g++ didn't like the idea.

Comment: It also doesn't like the idea of `void main` in a hosted implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your "common.h" placed? You must specify relative path to them from folder with the "Weapons.cpp".

At second, you define local variables in your functions. Your Weapons.cpp file must look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "relative/path/to/common.h"

//global variables
int pureDamage = 0;
int pureHealth = 0;
int weaponDamage;
int armorDefense;
int totalDamage = pureDamage + weaponDamage;
int totalHealth = pureHealth + armorDefense;
int totalLuck;
string starsign;
string weaponName;

using namespace std;

void weaponSwordIron()
{
    weaponDamage = 5;
    weaponName = "Iron Sword";
}
void weaponSwordGold()
{
    weaponDamage = 8;
    weaponName = "Gold Sword";
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the header location issues and local variable shadowing that others have mentioned, I think you're also going to run into problems with multiple definition errors:

```
extern int pureDamage = 0;
```

The initializer on this declaration overrides the `extern`, so this variable will be not only declared but also defined in any compilation unit that includes this header. Your linker will complain.

When you really want to use globals across multiple files you'll need to define and initialize the variable *once* in a source file and declare it `extern` (with no initializer) in the header file. `const` variables are an exception to this, however.

Comment: But please listen to what others are saying about design though, because this is a very poor way to design a program of any non-trivial size.